# Weakly mixing implies "weakly mixing on all orders"

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems

Suppose a probability perserving system $(X,\mathcal{B}_X,\mu,T)$ is weakly mixing (here $\mathcal{B}_X$ is Borel algebra of topology space $X$ and $\mu$ is a finite/probability measure), i.e.
$$
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{n=N-1}|\mu(A\cap T^{-n}B) - \mu(A)\mu(B)| \xrightarrow{N\to+\infty} 0
\quad \forall A,B \in \mathcal{B}_X
$$
And there are many equivalent description of weakly mixing. In Furstenberg's ergodic proof of Szemerédi's theorem (One can refer Furstenberg's paper in 1977) he proved weakly mixing implies "weakly mixing on all order for sets" like
$$
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{n=N-1}|\mu(T^{-n}A_1 \cap T^{-2n}A_2 \cap \cdots \cap T^{-kn}A_k) - \mu(A_1)\cdots \mu(A_k)| \xrightarrow{N\to+\infty} 0
\quad \forall A_1,..,A_k \in \mathcal{B}_X\tag*{(A)}
$$
In almost all existing references on this topic a so-called "van der Corpt trick
" on Hilbert space is used and by that technique one can prove stronger results than (A) for commutative weakly mixing operators. etc.

I suspect there is a more-straight way to prove (A) because using induction it is sufficient to show weakly mixing implies
$$
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{n=N-1}|\mu(T^{-n}A_1 \cap T^{-in}A_2 \cap T^{-jn}A_3) - \mu(A_1)\mu(A_2) \mu(A_3)| \xrightarrow{N\to+\infty} 0
\quad \forall A_1,A_2,A_3 \in \mathcal{B}_X,i,j\in\mathbb{N}^+\tag*{(B)}
$$
which means something like "3-weakly mixing".

If one can prove (B) then using some estimations on measures one can prove (A) by induction.

My question is does there exist a direct way to get (B)?

Comment: In order to show that (B) implies (A) one can use induction to estimate the difference between $\mu(\bigcup_{i\ge 2} A_i^c)$ and its measure products of components.

Comment: Or someone can show an counterexample of 2-weakly mixing(weakly mixing) not implying 3-weakly mixing.

Comment: In Furstenberg's paper the index of $T$ can be arbitrary $i_1,...,i_k$ (not only $1,..,k$). And his also deal with weakly mixing of the commutating families $\{T_{i}\}_{i\in I}$.